Google places autocomplete not loading
We are working on an angular project that uses the google places autocomplete to search addresses in the US. We have included the google places library in the index.html file. It was working as expected but lately the team has been facing an issue where the autocomplete component would not load and when the user clicks in to type an address it would show the following error
This page can't load Google Maps
Below is the code for reference

HTML

<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="add-search-input-container">
            <mat-icon matPrefix style="color: #757575;">search</mat-icon>
            <input [disabled]="googleForm.disabled" id="addressGooglePlaces-addressAutocomplete" matInput
                placeholder="Search address here or enter below" [(ngModel)]="autocompleteInput" #addresstext
                style="margin-left: 6px;">
        </div>
        <button id="addressGooglePlaces-null-btn" style="display: none;"></button>
    </div>


TypeScript


private getPlaceAutocomplete() {
    const center = { lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude };
    
    const defaultBounds = {
      north: center.lat + this.radius,
      south: center.lat - this.radius,
      east: center.lng + this.radius,
      west: center.lng - this.radius,
    };

    if (this.restrictAddressSearchToServiceableCitiesAndStates) { // this is to show the all USA address in search bar

      const autocomplete: any = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.addresstext?.nativeElement,
        {
          fields: ["address_components", "formatted_address"],
          types: [this.adressType]  // 'establishment' / 'address' / 'geocode'
        });

      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
        this.place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.checked = true;
        this.invokeEvent(this.place);
      });
    }
    else {
      const autocomplete: any = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.addresstext?.nativeElement,
        {
          bounds: defaultBounds,
          strictBounds: true,
          // componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' },
          fields: ["address_components", "formatted_address"],
          types: [this.adressType]  // 'establishment' / 'address' / 'geocode'
        });

      if (this.restrictToCountries !== "") {
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
          country: [this.restrictToCountries],
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
        this.place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.checked = true;
        this.invokeEvent(this.place);
      });
    }
  }


Maybe a problem with the api key?

no, the API key is valid and the billing information attached is also valid.

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea. Maybe if you can create a reproducible example (using jsfiddle, jsbin or something) I can try to help with the debug
